# Looping DisplayObject animation

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, displayobject, gsap

I have multiple object doing random movement with random speed. i wanted to repeat the animation.

I tried to use onComplete to restart each object once the animation end, but how could I specifically target it to that object? Currently its overflow

```
private function lineAnimation (e:DisplayObject):void
    {
        TweenLite.to (e,randomTime, {x:randomX, onComplete: lineAnimation(e)});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a callback for onComplete, you need to just pass the function itself.  By setting `onComplete: lineAnimation(e)`, it is executing lineAnimation again over and over.  As you need to pass the parameter, you can use an anonymous function for the callback like so:

```
private function lineAnimation (e:DisplayObject):void
{
    TweenLite.to(e, randomTime, {x:randomX, onComplete:function():void {lineAnimation(e)}});
}
```

Also since you are using TweenLite, you may want to check out [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) which has looping built-in so you can do something like so:

```
TweenMax.to(e, randomTime, {x:randomX, repeat:-1}); // -1 repeats indefinitely
```